# Direction angle or pointing a 3D angle to a position in space

Tags: delphi, vector, point, angle

I'm trying to point an entity to a 3D vector. (basically setting an entities angle so it points to a position in 3D space). At the moment, I'm stuck with getting an angle from a vector.

```
//Vectors in the bracket are 3D, first is the entity position, second is a position in space where I want to point at.
( myEntity.Pos - posToPointAt ).Angle
```

I'm currently stuck at transforming the direction vector into an angle. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works, you are missing an essential bit of information: in stead of using the entity position, you need to figure out what way your entity is pointing *right now*? Acquiring that info might be as simple as using your current rotation matrix and multiplying it with a unit vector down the z-axis (or whatever the "neutral" direction of the entity is), but that all depends on your particular setup.

Once you have *both* direction vectors (your current direction, and the direction to the new desired location... the last one being the normalized "myEntity.Pos - posToPointAt"), you use a function like below to calculate the rotation between the directions. Notice I use quaternions here, you might be needing a rotation matrix.

```
function RotationBetweenVectors( const aV1, aV2: TVector3): TQuaternion;
const
  EPSILON = 0.000001;

var
  v1: TVector3;
  v2: TVector3;
  dot: FloatT;
  s: FloatT;
  invS: FloatT;
  c: TVector3;

begin
  v1 := aV1.normalize;
  v2 := aV2.normalize;

  dot := VectorDotProduct( v1, v2 );

  if dot >= 1 then
  begin
      // INFO: DotProduct = 1 -> vectors are the same
      result := QUATERNION_IDENTITY
  end
  else if ( dot < EPSILON - 1 ) then
  begin
      raise Exception.create( '180 degree rotation currently not supported.' );
  end
  else
  begin
      s := sqrt( 2 * ( 1 + dot ));
      invS := 1 / s;

      c := VectorCrossProduct( v1, v2 );

      result.x := c.x * invS;
      result.y := c.y * invS;
      result.z := c.z * invS;
      result.w := 0.5 * s;
      result := result.normalize;
  end;
end;
```